# Batch script command automatically stops batch script

Tags: batch-file, gradle, cmd

I am experiencing a strange issue with the following batch script run via `cmd.exe` on Windows:

```
@echo off
gradle wrapper
gradlew build
pause
```

This batch script only ever executes the first command, i.e. `gradle wrapper`. After that, the batch script automatically terminates and the command `gradlew build` is never executed.

Is there any way I can force the batch script so that it cannot be stopped by `gradle wrapper` and continues its execution normally after `gradle wrapper` has been called?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have a feeling you may need to precede with call:

```
call gradle…
```

Comment: This is because `gradle` is a .bat or .cmd script. If it were a .exe, `CALL` would not be necessary.

Comment: You are a genius... this has been annoying me for hours